# Menu going behind flash in ipad

Tags: ipad, flash, drop-down-menu, z-index

```
http://www.livingcoloursdiving.com/en/diving-snorkling/diving
```

This is the site i am working on. There are 2 issue :

1) The dropdown menu is not working in any ie
2) The dropdown goes behind the flash video.

Following methods i did try after researching :
- tried z-index method 
- tried the wmode transparent and opaque (works in browsers on pc but not ipad)

Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Comment: No hover over events in touch devices.

Comment: huh? Yes i know that. If you click on the menu then the dropdown will go down and you'll see that it goes behind the youtube video.

Comment: No, navigation is in the header and video is in different container.